Failure of universal coefficient theorem for spectra
Let $X, E $ be spectra and assume that the smash product $X\otimes E$ is nullhomotopic. Does it follow that the mapping spectrum $\underline{map}_{Sp}(X,E)$ is also null-homotopic; is every map $X\to E$ nullhomotopic? Phrased differently, is $E$ itself always $E$-local.
I know this holds when either $X$ or $E$ is finite or, when $E$ is a homotopy ring spectrum. This is similair to the universal coefficient theorem as we ask, whether $E_*(X) =0 $ implies $E^*(X)=0$. I know, Adam constructed some universal coefficient spectral sequences but as far as I know they don't apply in general. Are there in general counterexamples? Does $KU/n$ admit a nonzero map to $\mathbb{Z}\otimes E$ for some spectrum $E$, even though $KU/n \otimes \mathbb{Z} \simeq 0$. Maybe one can proof the statement using truncations but I fear they don't work well-enough with the smash product.

Let $I$ be the Brown-Comenetz dual of the sphere. Then $I$ satisfies $I \wedge I =0$, but the identity map on $I$ is not null-homotopic.
